# PYTHON check for a program if it's up and running

Tags: python

I have a python script that parse some files, but sometimes appear unknown errors and script will fail.
So i tried to make a program that check for a file which have `timestamp pid`, and main program will update `timestamp` every 30 seconds.

```
def start_server():
    subprocess.Popen("C:\Server.py", shell=True)

while True:
    f = open('C:\server.conf', 'r+')
    text = f.read().split(' ')
    pid = int(text[0])
    lastTime = text[1]

    if float(time.time()) - float(lastTime) > 90:
        temp = subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /T /PID %i" % pid , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        out, err = temp.communicate()
        print ' [INFO] Server.py was killed, and started again.'
        start_server()
    time.sleep(30)
```

but this doesn't start new `server.py` if last instance of program will fail.
Any ideea how i can make this works?
Thanks!

Comment: Rather than writing a script which will restart your script when an error occurs, consider debugging your script so that errors no longer occur at all.

Comment: Are random problem, like network path not found because server `X` was down or something like that. So you comment it's a little bit useless..

Comment: @VladutZzZ The point is to catch that error and deal with it. For example, if server `X` is down, log the error, wait a while and then try again. In python, you can catch errors using exceptions with the `try except` syntax:  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html